# Why is J true for the limit of this graph?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having trouble understanding question letter J. Why is the limit of the graph 2 and not 0? Could anyone help me with question? Thanks. [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os6ws.png)

Comment: It is $0$.  There must be a typo on the answer sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks *which statements are true and which are false?*

The correct response is *j is false*.